# JQuery: how to append before last element (submit btn)

Tags: jquery, forms

I've a form like this. I'm using Jquery to append a div to a form (the div contains an input textarea field).

I do append it, but it goes after the submit button. I need this to be just before it.

Also, I should say I'm using Django but this shouldn't be a problem.

Should I use append, or other Jquery function?

**my Form:**

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

                {% csrf_token %}

                <div class="form-group hidden">
                    <p class="col-sm-3 control-label"> Nana ID: </p>
                    <p class="col-sm-3 control-label" value="{{ referencia.nana_id }}" name="nana_id"> {{ referencia.nana_id }} </p>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <p class="col-sm-3 control-label"> Nombre: </p>
                    <p class="col-sm-3 control-label"> {{ referencia.nombre_apellido }} </p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p class="col-sm-3 control-label"> Correo: </p>
                    <p class="col-sm-3 control-label"> {{ referencia.correo }} </p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p class="col-sm-3 control-label"> Teléfono: </p>
                    <p class="col-sm-3 control-label"> {{ referencia.telefono }} </p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p class="col-sm-3 control-label"> Dirección: </p>
                    <p class="col-sm-3 control-label"> {{ referencia.direccion }} </p>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="estado_referencia" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Estado de referencia</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                        <select id="estado_referencia" name="estado_referencia"
                                class="">
                            <option value="0">Pendiente</option>
                            <option value="1">No contesta</option>
                            <option value="2">Bueno</option>
                            <option value="3">Malo</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
                    <div class="button  control-label">
                        <a class=" btn btn-blue" type="submit">Modificar estado</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
```

**js file**:

```
$('#estado_referencia').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '1' || $(this).val() == '3') {

        if ($('div#comentario-textarea').length == 0) {

            $('form').append('<div id="comentario-textarea" class="form-group">\n' +
                '  <label for="comentario" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Comentario:</label>\n' +
                '  <textarea class="col-sm-3 control-label" rows="5" id="comentario" name="comentario"></textarea>\n' +
                '</div>');

        }

    } else {

        $('div#comentario-textarea').remove();

    }
});
```

Comment: Best practice any value reference perform more than once will be best assign a variable i.e `var $this` use `$( "<p>Test</p>" ).insertBefore( "form div:last" );`

Answer (score 1):

Use [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/) method to insert new element just before the selected one:

```
$('form .form-group:last').before('<div id="comentario-textarea" class="form-group">\n' +
            '  <label for="comentario" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Comentario:</label>\n' +
            '  <textarea class="col-sm-3 control-label" rows="5" id="comentario" name="comentario"></textarea>\n' +
            '</div>');
```

Comment: It worked after using "." before `form-group:last`, because it's a class. If you edit it, I'll set your answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: You have an event attached to `$('#estado_referencia')`, so inside it you can do `$(this).closest('.form-group').after(....);`